# Error when uploading media in wordpress website [update]

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using a wordpress blog theme that contains a signup/ login form for users.

When I login to the website using login form in the website and try to upload media from website, it will get an error:
[image]

In the other hand when I login to the website using example.com/wp-admin link and try to upload media from website, it works without any error!

Is there any code that I should add to the website to solve this issue?

I should also mention that the media is uploaded correctly from dahsboard without any error.

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you please tell which plugin do you use for the login or are you using custom login form for login page?
2. Please turn on Debug mode on and check Debug Log and share it here so we can help you out.

Comment: 1- The theme I'm using has no plugin for login form, it uses WP main functions. 2- sure I will.